# Is there anyway to use python to take a snapshot

Tags: python, screen, snapshot

Im working on a program and i was wondering if i can use python to snapshot my screen and possibly save it on my computer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, ImageGrab looks like it would work (http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagegrab.htm).

Comment: If you already have PIL ImageGrab works great